# Create new type of heading

Tags: header-footer

I want to create a new type of heading. The heading should look like this. [image]

The name of the header should be "Myheader". Right now I have solved the problem as followed:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Myheader}{\subsubsection}
\makeatother
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bf\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}]
```

I still want to be able to use the `\subsubsection` header, so the solution is not acceptable. A minimal example of the code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Myheader}{\subsubsection}
\makeatother
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bf\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}]
\begin{document}
\Myheader{The first appendix}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to solve this ??

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Is is for appendices? In the artcle class, appendices are `section`.

Comment: Of course, you must say `\appendix` when the appendices start, but each individual section of the appendix is done with `\section`. If you really wanted to, you could `\let\startappendices\appendix \let\appendix\section`. (This is all with `article` of course -- but most classes I've come across follow its lead.)

Comment: I want to create my own "section" in the appendix part look like this. In the main part the sections should look different, so therefore I have to make a \newcommand{\Myheader}

Comment: You should still have them as sections, though. Otherwise strange things are likely to happen. And welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the command issued to begin appendices so that `\section` will produce the right results after that point i.e. just for the appendices. This will ensure that your appendices are placed at the right level within the sectional hierarchy (e.g. for the ToC or for bookmarks) and make your code maximally flexible (e.g. if you change your mind, just remove the patch).

For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,etoolbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\apptocmd\appendix{%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
  \titleformat{\section}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bfseries\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}]
}{\typeout{Appendices title formatting successfully patched. Expect the expected.}}{\typeout{Appendices title formatting could not be patched. Unexpected results paradoxically to be expected.}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\kant[1]
\section{Another section}
\kant[2]
\appendix
\section{The first appendix}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: patched appendix]

## EDIT

In the comments you asked how to modify this to get empty headers on pages with `\section` after `\appendix` is issued. Your comment leads me to assume you are using `fancyhdr`. Without knowing the code you are currently using for headers elsewhere, it is difficult to specify the best way to do this but if you have something reasonably standard, this should work.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,etoolbox,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[lh]{\leftmark}
\fancyhf[rh]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{ancy}{%
  \fancyhf[h]{}%
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}%
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\apptocmd\appendix{%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
  \titleformat{\section}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bfseries\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}\thispagestyle{ancy}]
}{\typeout{Appendices title formatting successfully patched. Expect the expected.}}{\typeout{Appendices title formatting could not be patched. Unexpected results paradoxically to be expected.}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\kant[1-4]
\section{Another section}
\kant[5]
\appendix
\section{The first appendix}
\kant[6-8]
\end{document}
```

[image: no headers on new section in appendices]

Notice that this is a literal interpretation of your description and may or may not be what you want. In particular:

- `\section` following `\appendix` empties the header on the current page, even if the page also includes a `\section` prior to `\appendix`;
- pages following `\appendix` include a standard header if they do not include `\section`.

If you don't want headers after `\appendix` at all. You could use:

```
\apptocmd\appendix{%
  \pagestyle{ancy}%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
  \titleformat{\section}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bfseries\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}\thispagestyle{ancy}]
}{\typeout{Appendices title formatting successfully patched. Expect the expected.}}{\typeout{Appendices title formatting could not be patched. Unexpected results paradoxically to be expected.}}
```

[image: no headers in appendices at all]

The other possibilities here are more complex so I'll only think about those if necessary. In that case, I will work from your current code for the headers because it will probably be easiest to move away from `fancyhdr` at that point. `titleps` complements `titlesec` and would work well here.

## EDIT EDIT

In response to your query about patching `\tableofcontents` in a similar way, you can certainly do this. However, I admit that I've got a bit lost in terms of what exactly everything is supposed to look like, and I couldn't really figure out the purpose of the code you posted exactly. (But explicit page breaks and page numbering shouldn't be in the definition of a page style.)

I did this:

```
\pretocmd\tableofcontents{%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
  \titleformat{\section}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bfseries\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}\thispagestyle{ancy}]
}{\typeout{Contents title formatting successfully patched. Expect the expected.}}{\typeout{Contents title formatting could not be patched. Unexpected results paradoxically to be expected.}}
\apptocmd\tableofcontents{%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*5}{*2.5}%
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1.5em}{}[\thispagestyle{fancy}]
}{\typeout{Contents title formatting successfully patched again. Expect the expected.}}{\typeout{Contents title formatting could not be patched again. Unexpected results paradoxically to be expected.}}
```

which gives me this

[image: fancy contents]

But I suspect, now, that you are really just using the wrong class. If you were to use `book` or `report` a lot more of this would be there for you anyway. With `book`, for example, you get `\frontmatter`, \mainmatter`and`\backmatter`which are starting to look suspiciously like code you are trying to create here. If so, don't reinvent the wheel - use the right tool for the job and choose`book`or a`book`-like class.

Comment: @Simon You're welcome. When you are ready, don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most. (Click on the greyed out check mark at the top left of the answer you want to accept.)

Comment: Two things: First what is the purpose of: \typeout{Appendices title formatting successfully patched. Expect the expected.}}{\typeout{Appendices title formatting could not be patched. Unexpected results paradoxically to be expected.} ? What does it do ?

Second: Is it possible not to make a header on the pages where I use \sections{} after the \appendix command ? What I want is \fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{} \fancyhead[R]{} to be blank on those pages. I hope it isn't too much trouble for you. I'm new at latex.

Comment: @Simon The `\typeout` just prints a message on the console/to the log file telling you what has or hasn't been done. It is there to make diagnosing any problems easier: the output reminds you that the command has been altered so that you can consider it as a source of any problems, or, alternatively, it alerts you to the fact that the patch failed so that you know that may be the issue.

Comment: @Simon For the second question: yes, it is possible. Could you update your question with the code you are using for the headers prior to the appendices? Do you want a header on the first page of the appendices if there's pre-appendix material there? I'll have a guess based on what you've put in the comment but the actual code would be better.

Comment: @Simon Do you want a header on pages in the appendices where there is no `\section` command?

Comment: @Simon See edit. Is one of those possibilities what you want?

Comment: I have used a pagestyle{Backstyle} before the appendix part, and it seems to work. 
\fancypagestyle{Backstyle}{%
\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{{\nouppercase{\small\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\sffamily\bfseries\datoen}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\sffamily\bfseries \thechapter \@\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}
}

Comment: But thanks again for your help. I'm really grateful for it.

Comment: @Simon Glad you sorted it. I was a bit in the dark as to what precisely you wanted ;).

Comment: haha yeah it wasn't perhaps the best description. Sorry about that.

Comment: Btw. is it posible to make the same header for the table of contents as you did for the appendix where you used: \apptocmd\appendix{%....}. Is it clear what I'm looking for ?

Comment: @Simon How would that work? The contents is an unnumbered section whereas the sections in the appendix are numbered. So you can do it, for sure, but it won't look the same because there will be no large letter or number there. Of course, you could number it but that would be a bit odd.

Comment: Yeah sure, bad description for me again. I will try to do better. For sure I want the title unnumbered for the table of contents. How do I do that ?

Comment: @Simon It is unnumbered by default. But it isn't clear what it should look like. Just the title and the line? Since there is no number to be large and on the right, it can't use just the same style as the sections in the appendix.

Comment: Yes, just the title and the line.

Comment: @Simon See edit. But I think you are probably just using the wrong class and should switch to a more appropriate one ;).

Comment: Thanks again. Yeah perhaps. Its something between the report and article class. I didn't want the chapters, so I thought the article class would fit best. But now it is like I want it. Thanks for all your help.